# SQL Query from php vs direct SQL query to the database

Tags: php, sql

Executing the following query at the SQL manager (sqlite manager),

```
   SELECT ip FROM objects WHERE name="machine4"
```

returns the expected value, an ip address = 'aaaa::c30c:0:0:4'.

Executing the same query from the php code as following,

```
  $db=open_database();
  $query = $db->exec('SELECT ip FROM objects WHERE name="machine4"');   
  echo $query;
```

gives in return the value 1.

Is there anything escaping from my acquaintance about php?

p.s.: i'm sure that the queries are executed without error, and they access the same database referencing to the same element.

Comment: It returns 1 because you're not using some form of fetching loop. Or, am I not grasping the question? You looking for something that will prevent injection or `aaaa::c30c:0:0:4`? If it's SQL injection prevention, use prepared statements.

Comment: Which DB library is being used?  What is `$db` a mysqli connection object?  I'm guessing, PDO.

Comment: Is it really that hard to just read the documentation?

Comment: Not sure what DB management library extension you are using, but pretty much everyone of them returns a results set to a `query()` or `exec()` type of command.  You then need to work with that result set (i.e. `fetch_*()` to get the data out of the result set.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. Documentation has the answer. I've assumed that the exec would return the query, looking to examples with insertions. Basic error for a beginner!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

First I would need an object to fetch the value, for that purpose exec does not return an object but the number of rows afected as mentioned. While the [query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) command from php, has an object to fetch.

This is the answer for the query applied to the SQLITE3 db:

```
$db=open_database();
$query = $db->query('SELECT ip FROM objects WHERE name="machine4"');
if(!$query){
   echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} else {
   $ip=$query->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
   return $ip['ip'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just returns number of rows affected http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php
All the methods
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: This answer is better served as a comment (though, I know you can't comment till 50 rep). To make this a **good** answer, you should add some additional explanation and a simple, working example.